# Getting the urls params in a page using jquery

Tags: jquery, parameters, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get QueryString values in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-in-javascript)

Hey all,

ive read and read and i feel im missing something so im going to ask.

what im trying to do:

get the url params from page using jquery.

```
function findIt() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "${url.context}/itemlist/getitemlist",
        params: "foobar",
        context: document.body,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#results').html(data);

        }
    });
};
```

the url in which im sending the params to is where i need to grab the parameters using jquery.

e.g. in Php:

```
$foo = $_GET['name']
```

in jquery?????

i know this has to be simple, but im lost. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-in-javascript) for tons of possible solutions.

Comment: some of these are coming up as undefined when i alert the param